# Converting string extracted from json value to date returning NULL

Tags: mysql, json, datetime, string-to-datetime

I'm saving a date in one db field in json format. The json value looks like:

```
[{"key":"jkajdajsdiajsdik"},{"created_date":"2018-01-17 15:51:23"}]
```

I want to extract the `created_date` from json through sql and i'm getting it through the following query.

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(testjson, 'created_date\":', -1),'}',1) as created_date from test
```

The above query returns

```
"2018-01-17 15:51:23"
```

Now I'm trying to convert this returned string to a date.

```
select STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(testjson, 'created_date\":', -1),'}',1),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as created_date from test
```

But this is returning NULL. When I tried with a sample

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(" 2018-01-17 15:51:23",'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

Its returning

```
2018-01-17 15:51:23
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ? Newer versions have JSON specific functions available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is also including `"`. Make this small change to your code to exclude them:

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(testjson, 'created_date":"', -1),'"}',1) as created_date from test
--                                                              ^        ^
-- -------------------------------------------------------------+        |
-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

The date returned after `Substring_Index()` operations also contains double quotes. I added double quotes in the format specified for the `Str_to_Date()` function:

```
select STR_TO_DATE(
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(
               SUBSTRING_INDEX(testjson, 'created_date\":', -1),'}'
               ,1)
           ,'"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"') 
AS created_date from test
```

**Result**

```
| created_date        |
| ------------------- |
| 2018-01-17 15:51:23 |
```

[**View on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eATUBhhJeEYKtdmNobRpa/0)

---

However, in version 5.7 and above, it would be better to utilize JSON functions instead. We can use [`Json_Extract()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) function to get the value corresponding to `created_date` key, and the use the `Str_To_Date()` function.

**Query #2**

```
SET @j := '[{"key":"jkajdajsdiajsdik"},{"created_date":"2018-01-17 15:51:23"}]';

SELECT STR_TO_DATE(JSON_EXTRACT(@j, '$[*].created_date'), '["%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"]') AS created_date;
```

**Result**

```
| created_date        |
| ------------------- |
| 2018-01-17 15:51:23 |
```

[**View on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eATUBhhJeEYKtdmNobRpa/1)

Comment: @Jenz happy to help. Check the updated answer; it will be better to use JSON functions, if your MySQL version supports it.